# Unity create texture from TGA

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, textures, texture2d

I try to generate sprites from StreamingAsets folder but I'm stuck when it comes to create texture from formats other than PNG and JPG. Following code:

```
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes (filepath);    // 256x256 .tga image file
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D (1, 1);
    texture.LoadImage (bytes);
```

generates 8x8 texture which is:

- wrong considered my image is 256x256,
- expected, since Texture2D.LoadImage is meant to work with PNGs and JPGs.

So how do I create textures from other types of images?

Comment: LoadImage only load jpg or png, is not you got a wrong size image how your experimenting.
You try  LoadRawTextureData setting the image size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TGA format is not supported. You have to write your own wrapper to do so but many of these wrappers do exist already. See the [`TGALoader`](https://gist.github.com/mikezila/10557162) class. It is very simple to use.

```
Texture2D texture = TGALoader.LoadTGA(sfilepath);
```

Your TGA image is now loaded into the `texture` variable.

Comment: Whoa! Done it! TGALoader was great basis though I had to update script to be able to read RLE compressed images.